# Could Real Numbers Be Countable If They Were Defined Slightly Differently?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

The alternative definition would be such that real numbers have varying lengths based on the number of trailing zeros they traditionally had.

So, something like $0.0000000$... is just $0$, and something like $0.0$ doesn't exist.

Now, since there are only a finite number of digits in the decimal number system $0-9$, could all real numbers can be arranged in terms of the number of digits they have -- with reals having equal number of digits being arranged according to their decimal values?

Would this set be countable, or is there a flaw in this logic?

Comment: $0.00000...,0.0,$ and $0$ are already the same thing.

Comment: What about rational numbers like $1/3=0.\overline{3}$ or irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}=1.4142...$? These number wouldn't be real numbers under your proposed system as they have an infinite number of digits.

Comment: The set of real numbers whose decimal expansions terminate (*i.e. who have only finitely many digits*) are indeed countable (*they are a subset of the rational numbers which we know to be a countable set*).  There are of course real numbers which do not have terminating decimal expansions (*or even repeating decimal expansions, e.g. $\sqrt{2}$*) so this set does not cover the entirety of the real numbers.

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what you have in mind: personally, all I can gather from your example is that your method would not allow numbers with a finite number of digit (in a way which should presumably, but not evidently, be different from the existing one). Yet, you subsequently wish to list the real numbers through enumeration of digits. However, I think the answer is no nevertheless.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a number with its decimal expansion(s).